# Magento Configurable Product String Error

Tags: string, magento, configurable-product, configurable

When clicking on a configurable product in the category view I'm redirected to a blank white page with the following error:

string(59) "http://www.smashingcases.co.uk/configurable-iphone-product1"

What I've noticed is that the URL above in quotes is missing the category. It's strange because the category appears in the URL in the browser:

http://www.smashingcases.co.uk/personalised-cases/configurable-iphone-product1

This is the first time I've attempted to build a configurable product so it could be something really simple but I can't for the life of me figure out what this string error is and why it's showing a URL with the category missing?

I've also tried making configurable products in different categories (but using the same attribute set) and I still have the same problem..

Could it be something to do with the attribute set up?

I'm using Magento 1.8 with Milano theme.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to Flush Cache Storage & Flush Magento Cache inside Magento Admin: System -> Cache Management

I am able to see the configurable product. You need to add proper attributes & costs to see change in value.
If unable to configure, ping me a user with product creation access. I can help you with that.

Do notify if it solves your issue.